# Textual parsing

Tags: python, html, pandas

I am a newby with Python and Panda, but i would like to parse from multiple downloaded files (which have the same format).
On every HTML there is an section like below where the executives are mentioned.

```
<DIV id=article_participants class="content_part hid">
<P>Redhill Biopharma Ltd. (NASDAQ:<A title="" href="http://seekingalpha.com/symbol/rdhl" symbolSlug="RDHL">RDHL</A>)</P>
<P>Q4 2014 <SPAN class=transcript-search-span style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: yellow">Earnings</SPAN> Conference <SPAN class=transcript-search-span style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #f38686">Call</SPAN></P>
<P>February 26, 2015 9:00 AM ET</P>
<P><STRONG>Executives</STRONG></P>
<P>Dror Ben Asher - CEO</P>
<P>Ori Shilo - Deputy CEO, Finance and Operations</P>
<P>Guy Goldberg - Chief Business Officer</P>
```

and further in the files there is a section called "DIV id=article_qanda class="content_part hid"  where the executives like Ori Shilo is named followed by an answer, like:

```
<P><STRONG><SPAN class=answer>Ori Shilo</SPAN></STRONG></P>
<P>Good morning, Vernon. Both safety which is obvious and fertility analysis under the charter of the data and safety monitoring board will be - will be on up.</P>
```

Till now i only succeeded with an html parser for one individual by name to collect all their answers. I am not sure how to proceed and base the code on a variable list of executives. Does someone have a suggestion?

```
import textwrap
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

directory ='C:/Research syntheses - Meta analysis/SeekingAlpha/out'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.html'):
        fname = os.path.join(directory,filename)
        with open(fname, 'r') as f:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(),'html.parser')

print('{:<30} {:<70}'.format('Name', 'Answer'))
print('-' * 101)
for answer in soup.select('p:contains("Question-and-Answer Session") ~ strong:contains("Dror Ben Asher") + p'):
    txt = answer.get_text(strip=True)

    s = answer.find_next_sibling()
    while s:
        if s.name == 'strong' or s.find('strong'):
            break
        if s.name == 'p':
            txt += ' ' + s.get_text(strip=True)
        s = s.find_next_sibling()

    txt = ('\n' + ' '*31).join(textwrap.wrap(txt))

    print('{:<30} {:<70}'.format('Dror Ben Asher - CEO', txt), file=open("output.txt", "a"))
```

Comment: I think you're well on your way already, your first attempt looks good. You're going to want to replace the hard-coded parts of your code with parameters. [Functions](https://www.pitt.edu/~naraehan/python3/user_defined_functions.html) will be your friend here. In reference to your actual question, SO is not meant as a code-writing service, so give it your best shot, and when you get stuck, we will be here to help. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What is On-Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I read the function link you posted, but i don't understand how i could make my executives found and used by "functions". Could you give an example? Of course i don't expect this to be a code-writing-service.

Answer (score 0):

To give some color to my original comment, I'll use a simple example. Let's say you've got some code that is looking for the string "Hello, World!" in a file, and you want the line numbers to be aggregated into a list. Your first attempt might look like:

```py
# where I will aggregate my results
line_numbers = []

with open('path/to/file.txt') as fh:
    for num, line in enumerate(fh):
        if 'Hello, World!' in line:
            line_numbers.append(num)
```

This code snippet works perfectly well. However, it only works to check `'path/to/file.txt'` for `'Hello, World!'`.

Now, you want to be able to change the string you are looking for. This is analogous to saying "I want to check for different executives". You could use a function to do this. A function allows you to add flexibility into a piece of code. In this simple example, I would do:

```py
# Now I'm checking for a parameter string_to_search
# that I can change when I call the function
def match_in_file(string_to_search):
    line_numbers = []

    with open('path/to/file.txt') as fh:
        for num, line in enumerate(fh):
            if string_to_search in line:
                line_numbers.append(num)

    return line_numbers


# now I'm just calling that function here
line_numbers = match_in_file("Hello, World!")
```

You'd still have to make a code change, but this becomes much more powerful if you wanted to search for lots of strings. I could feasibly use this function in a loop if I wanted to (though I would do things a little differently in practice), for the sake of the example, I now have the power to do:

```py
list_of_strings = [
    "Hello, World!",
    "Python",
    "Functions"
]

for s in list_of_strings:
    line_numbers = match_in_file(s)
    print(f"Found {s} on lines ", *line_numbers)
```

Generalized to your specific problem, you'll want a parameter for the `executive` that you want to search for. Your function signature might look like:

```py
def find_executive(soup, executive):
    for answer in soup.select(f'p:contains("Question-and-Answer Session") ~ strong:contains({executive}) + p'):
        # rest of code
```

You've already read in the `soup`, so you don't need to do that again. You only need to change the executive in your select statement. The reason you want a parameter for `soup` is so you aren't relying on variables in global scope.

Answer (score 0):

@C.Nivs Would my code then be the following? Because i now get a block error:

```
import textwrap
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

directory ='C:/Research syntheses - Meta analysis/SeekingAlpha/'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.html'):
        fname = os.path.join(directory,filename)
        with open(fname, 'r') as f:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(),'html.parser')

print('{:<30} {:<70}'.format('Name', 'Answer'))
print('-' * 101)
def find_executive(soup, executive):
    for answer in soup.select(f'p:contains("Question-and-Answer Session") ~ strong:contains({executive}) + p'):
    txt = answer.get_text(strip=True) 
    s = answer.find_next_sibling()
    while s:
        if s.name == 'strong' or s.find('strong'):
            break
        if s.name == 'p':
            txt += ' ' + s.get_text(strip=True)
        s = s.find_next_sibling()

    txt = ('\n' + ' '*31).join(textwrap.wrap(txt))

    print('{:<30} {:<70}'.format(func, txt), file=open("output.txt", "a"))
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't even see this got posted. I'll take some time to go through it. In the future, a simple comment on an answer or in your question paired with an edit works perfectly, otherwise, I'll never get notified

Comment: @C.Nivs Awesome. I think what is still missing is the fact that i need to derive first the executives from the Div id=article_participants class="content_part hid"> the P STRONG Executives STRONG
Dror Ben Asher - CEO
Ori Shilo - Deputy CEO, Finance and Operations
Guy Goldberg - Chief Business Officer 
And use these as input to search in the question and answer session.